# Issue with rendering fire on Transparency

Tags: rendering, transparency, fire

I am having an issue with rendering fire on a transparent background. I've gone into the world and changed the alpha from the sky to transparency. I've checked the transparent box under the render properties, under the film section. However, when I do this only my emitter renders, not my fire simulation. Unchecking the box under the film section causes renders to return to normal. Any help would be appreciated. Wondering if something is setup incorrectly with my nodes? Or If I am missing some setting.

Thanks!

[image] [image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Renders at 10% Added

Comment: Can  you upload the file? You can use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for this.

Comment: Added Thanks Crantisz! I mostly followed a tutorial as I don't quite understand all the settings yet.

Comment: I saw that, but it isn't a viewer only issue, renders aren't correct. Also, whereas that post has the fire still visible, although not displaying correctly. Mine has nothing except the emitter displaying.

Comment: It's exactly your question. The only difference is that  your fire visible because you have non-transparency emitter behind it

Comment: What does make you think renders aren't correct? Did you try overlaying rendered image over some solid color to check? Note also that render output should be saved to OpenEXR to allow correct work with transparency

Comment: Yeah, I've overlayed it on a solid color and there is nothing other than the emitter showing up, not so much as one particle of fire. ;)  I've tried saving as both exr and a png with rgba turned on.

Comment: Perhaps, I am not reading the article right? I can't use a blue or green screen because it doesn't key nicely with the fire element. What other options do I have?